# Javascript Confirm() dynamic text based on row in GridView

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0

Is there a way to customize the dialog displayed in the Confirm text box to reflect the item you are referencing? I was thinking something like...

```
OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete' + '<%# Eval("Name") %>')"
```

But I keep getting a 'server tag isn't well formed' error when I try to use this format. Does anyone know of a solution?

Comment: In the past, I've done this: in the GridView's `RowDataBound` handler, I find the control in the row and set its `OnClientClick` property. I'm not sure if it's a problem with your quotes, but I remember having trouble doing what you're doing, so I had to set it on the server. At the same time, you could give the controls a specific class, then in JavaScript, find all of those elements and bind an event to them for confirmation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the "this" object in javascript to know the context

For example:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function tryDelete(button) {
            var itemName = getItemName(button);
            return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete '" + itemName + "'?");
        }

        function getItemName(button) {
            return button.parentElement.parentElement.children[1].innerHTML;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="cmdDelete" runat="server" Text="delete" OnClientClick="return tryDelete(this);" /></td>
                <td>Item 1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="delete" OnClientClick="return tryDelete(this);" /></td>
                <td>Item 2</td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work ...I don't know any ASP  but in PHP it would go something like:

```
OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete <?php echo $name; ?>')"
```

in your case I'm guessing it should be something like:

```
OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete <%# Eval("Name") %>')"
```

Comment: That's what I thought too. But, alas, it doesn't work I'm assuming it's just some weird buggy thing. I'm going to give what Ian said a go. Thanks for the response though.